# How to get output in a specified format

Tags: output-formatting, data-format, fortran

In Fortran, we can easily get the stardard and easy output format. Now, we only focus on the Integer output. See [here](http://www.cs.mtu.edu/%7Eshene/COURSES/cs201/NOTES/chap05/INT-out.html)
How to realize this kind of output as formatted text file using Mathematica ? (Then it can be read in Fortran easily).Take a simple example, I have a list,

```
   list=Table[(i + j) i (i - j), {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 22}];
```

I want to get the output data in a text file and

1. Every integer should be printed with 6 positions. (It is I6 in Fortran).
2. The  maximum line length in the text file should be limited to 120.

   [image]

Comment: Your question is not clear. Is your goal to format output in a _Mathematica_ notebook, or is it exporting your data to disk as formatted text?

Comment: To obtain the formatted text file.

Comment: OK, but in a file or on the screen in a notebook window?

Comment: The output should be stored in a text file.

Comment: Is the maximum line length something you are supplying and is represented in the actual file, _e.g._ `-399\n  -440`, or were you just saying that's how the file would look in an editor whose maximum line length is set to 120.

Comment: The maximum line length is a requirement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
data = Table[(i + j) i (i - j), {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 22}];
```

The first step is to define a function to break up each row in the data into lines not exceeded the specified maximum line length.

```
prep[row_, fieldWidth_, lineLength_] :=
  Module[{items = Floor[lineLength/fieldWidth]}, 
    Partition[row, items, items, 1, {}]]
```

The second step is to do the breaking. I have shorten the lines to 80 characters for better looking output to show here.

```
lines = Flatten[prep[#, 6, 80] & /@ data, 1];
```

The third step is to make the strings

```
output = 
  StringJoin @@@ 
    Map[StringTake[StringJoin["     ", ToString@#], -6] &, lines, {2}]
```

The final step is to export the strings. I use `ExportString` for demonstration.

```
ExportString[output, "Text"]
```

[image: output]

You can use something similar to

```
Export["~/Desktop/test.txt", output, "Text"]
```

to put the strings into a disk file.

#### Update

As suggested by SjoerdC.deVries in a comment,

```
output = 
  StringJoin @@@ 
    Map[ToString[NumberForm[#, 6, NumberPadding -> " "]] &, lines, {2}];
```

is an alternative way to make the strings.

Comment: How about IntegerString?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries. Not sure what you are getting at, but consider that `IntegerString[-42, 10, 6]` gives `"000042"`. To munge that into the form I actually need doesn't seem better than what I did.

Comment: OK, that was too quick. How about `NumberForm[-42, 6, NumberPadding -> " "] // ToString` then?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries. That'a good idea. I added an update giving it as an alternative.